# Problema com ToString no Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Tenho variáveis do tipo String e variáveis do tipo Int. Quando faço `getText.ToString()` em uma variável do tipo int o Android Studio apresente erro devido ao tipo de variável não ser uma String.

Alguém saberia qual opção eu posso usar para as variáveis do tipo Int?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
package studio.com.projetofinal;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.List;

public class CadastroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private DBcadastro dh;
    EditText etnome, etcpf, etidade, ettelefone, etemail;
    Button InserirDB;
    Button ListarCadastro;


    Button btvoltar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);

        btvoltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.voltar);
        btvoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                voltarHome();
            }
        });

        this.dh = new DBcadastro(this);
        etnome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnome);
        etcpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcpf);
        etidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etidade);
        ettelefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettelefone);
        etemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemail);

        InserirDB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.InserirDB);
        ListarCadastro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ListarCadastro);

        InserirDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (etnome.getText().length()>0 && etcpf.getText().length()>0 && etidade.getText().length()>0 && ettelefone.getText().length()>0 && etemail.getText().length()>0){
                    dh.insert(etnome.getText().toString(),etcpf.getText().toString(),etidade.getText().toString(),ettelefone.getText().toString(),etemail.getText().toString());
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadastroActivity.this);
                    adb.setTitle("Sucesso");
                    adb.setMessage("Cadastro Realizado!");
                    adb.show();

                    etnome.setText("");
                    etcpf.setText("");
                    etidade.setText("");
                    ettelefone.setText("");
                    etemail.setText("");

            }else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadastroActivity.this);
                    adb.setTitle("Erro");
                    adb.setMessage("Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos!");
                    adb.show();

                    etnome.setText("");
                    etcpf.setText("");
                    etidade.setText("");
                    ettelefone.setText("");
                    etemail.setText("");
                }
        }

    });

     ListarCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

             List<cadastro> cadastro = dh.queryGetALL();
             if(cadastro == null){
                 AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadastroActivity.this);
                 adb.setTitle("Mensagem");
                 adb.setMessage("Não há registros cadastrados!");
                 adb.show();

                 etnome.setText("");
                 etcpf.setText("");
                 etidade.setText("");
                 ettelefone.setText("");
                 etemail.setText("");
                 return;
             }

             for (int i=0;i<cadastro.size();i++){
                 cadastro cadsatro = (cadastro) cadastro.get(i);
                 AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadastroActivity.this);
                 adb.setTitle("Registro "+ i);
                 adb.setMessage("Nome: "+ cadsatro.getNome()+ "\nCPF: "+ cadsatro.getCpf() + "\nIdade: "+ cadsatro.getIdade() +
                         "\nTelefone: " + cadsatro.getTelefone() + "\n Email: " + cadsatro.getTelefone());
                 adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         dialog.dismiss();
                     }
                 });

                 adb.show();
             }


         }


     });


    void voltarHome(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(CadastroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente na função `dh.insert` você deve recer int, então faça o parse: `Integer.parseInt(campo.getText().toString())` ou `Integer.valueOf(campo.getText().toString())`, não lembro

Comment: Ok Guilherme Costamilam esta solução que você sugeriu funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Android Studio está reclamando que o método `insert()` espera 3 parâmetros do tipo `int`, mas você os está passando como `String`, justamente por utilizar o método `toString()`. Não faz muito sentido.

Nesse caso, você tem que usar a classe *wrapper* `Integer`, mais especificamente o método `parseInt()`, que vai pegar o conteúdo do `EditText` e convertê-lo para um valor inteiro, retornando um `int`:

```
Integer.parseInt(campo.getText().toString())
```

Comment: Ok StatelessDev esta solução que você sugeriu funcionou.

Comment: Se a resposta lhe ajudou, marque-a como correta para ajudar futuros usuários que tenham um problema similar ao seu.